# Python keybd_event problems

Tags: python, winapi, emulation, keyboard-events

For a personal project, I want to generate keyboard presses for a N64 emulator. It seems like it recognizes only one keyboard event when I select the Python IDE then switch to the emulator. I want the emulator to constantly recognize the button presses the python script generates. The code is really simple, it constantly replicates the x button being pressed.

```
import serial,win32api, win32con,time
while 1:
        win32api.keybd_event(0x58,0x2D,0,0)
        time.sleep(1)
```